# JPQL - multiple joins with OR

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm using JPA and wondering the best way to construct this query.

Here is my data model (this is totally contrived and non-sensical):
Table "Thing" has a many-to-many relationship with tables "Height" "Width" and "Length"
Height, Width, Length each have a many-to-one relationship with table "Creator"

For a given Thing, I would like all the Creators associated with at least one of Height, Width, or Length (note that a single thing can have many heights - as I said it's contrived).

For example, if I was only concerned about Height, I would do this:

`SELECT c FROM Creator c

INNER JOIN c.heights height

WHERE height.thing = :thing`

Is there a way to specify multiple inner joins with OR?  I'm assuming multiple inner joins would function as boolean AND.

Here's my current best guess:

`SELECT c FROM Creator c

WHERE EXISTS (SELECT h FROM Height h WHERE h.creator = c AND h.thing = :thing)

OR EXISTS (SELECT w FROM Width w WHERE w.creator = c AND w.thing = :thing)

OR EXISTS (SELECT l FROM Length l WHERE l.creator = c AND l.thing = :thing)`

Is there a better way to construct this query?  My real-world case has about 10 elements in the height-width-length collection.

Answer (score 0):

OR will work with inner joins as long as the relationship exists (as long as the Creator has any heights, regardless of your condition).  If the relationship is empty or null, then you need to use an outer join, or a sub-select.

I believe and outer join would perform better than a sub-select, but it may depend on the database.

Comment: I'm never quite sure how structuring a JPQL query translates to performance since the generated SQL usually seems pretty unwieldy anyway.